# Using Spark DataFrame filter with a List of column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to filter non-null column values in a Spark DataFrame using a `List[String]`:

```
val keyList = List("columnA", "columnB", "columnC", "columnD", ...)
```

For a single column named `key`, the syntax should be :

```
val nonNullDf = df.filter(col("key").isNotNull)
```

My question is how to use the `keyList` into the previous filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a filter by doing a map-reduce on `keyList`.

Use `and` if you want to keep the rows where all columns are not null, or use `or` if you want to keep the rows where any column is not null.

```
val nonNullDf = df.filter(keyList.map(col(_).isNotNull).reduce(_ and _))
```